# Swiftui popup when clicking text

Tags: text, swiftui, menu, popup

I just started learning swiftui and im trying to figure out how to recreate the following popup when clicking on a word: [image]

What i want to recreate is the ability to have this sort of popup directly under or above the specific word, whenever clicking on it.

How is this functionality called in swiftui? Now my best guess is that it uses a Menu which calls a function when clicking on it, that then displays popup, which is customized to make it look like it does now. Is that correct?

If not, can you point me to the right documentation or names of this functionality.

Comment: The simplest way is to make the clickable text a borderless `Button` .On macOS you then can use `.popover`. On iOS that would show differently, so you would have to create your own view e.g. in an `.overlay`

Comment: or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70970924/how-to-detect-a-tap-on-a-link-and-tap-coordinates-at-the-same-time-in-swiftui

Answer (score 0):

That component is also known as PopTip, and it is very popular in UIKit. In SwiftUI you can achive that just setting a variable to show and hide the popup:

```
@State var isInfoPopTipShown: Bool = false
```

Inside **var body: some View {}** create an icon view:

```
private var iconView: some View {
        Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
            .foregroundStyle(.purple)
    }
```

Then create a button using above iconView and explore the benefits of .popover(...):

> popover(isPresented: Binding, attachmentAnchor:
> PopoverAttachmentAnchor = .rect(.bounds), arrowEdge: Edge = .top,
> @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View where
> Content : View

```
Button {
            isInfoPopTipShown.toggle()
        } label: {
            iconView
                .popover(isPresented: self.$isInfoPopTipShown,
                         attachmentAnchor: .point(.top),
                         arrowEdge: .top,
                         content: {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Coder get your stuff and")
                        Text("let's have fun!!")
                    }
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .lineLimit(0)
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                    .padding()
                    .presentationCompactAdaptation(.none)
                })
        }
```

**Full code to copy** [***here***](https://github.com/Joule87/CodeSamples/blob/main/PopTipDemoSwiftUI/PopTipDemoView.swift)

[image]